# jQuery clone not working with syncfusion controls

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net-core, syncfusion

[image]I have a div with syncfusion controls inside of it. When cloned they do not appear as expected in the copied div. Syncfusion adds their own custom scripts to the controls on page load, so you will see I am doing the same after the clone.

Please see the below declarations in HTML:

```
<div id="abc" class="row">
    <div id="xyz" class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header applicant-title">
                <span>Applicant 1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].SocialSecurityNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <ejs-maskedtextbox id="Applicants_0__SocialSecurityNumber" name="Applicants[0].SocialSecurityNumber" mask="000-00-0000"></ejs-maskedtextbox>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].SocialSecurityNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].Birthdate" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <ejs-datepicker id="Applicants_0__Birthdate" name="Applicants[0].Birthdate" placeholder="Choose a Date"></ejs-datepicker>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].Birthdate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].PhoneNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <ejs-maskedtextbox id="Applicants_0__PhoneNumber" name="Applicants[0].PhoneNumber" mask="(999)-999-9999"></ejs-maskedtextbox>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].WorkPhoneNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <ejs-maskedtextbox id="Applicants_0__WorkPhoneNumber" name="Applicants[0].WorkPhoneNumber" mask="(999)-999-9999"></ejs-maskedtextbox>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].WorkPhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].Points" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <ejs-numerictextbox id="Applicants_0__Points" name="Applicants[0].Points" maxlength="2" format="n" Type="text" showSpinButton="false" showClearButton="false" min="0" max="50"></ejs-numerictextbox>
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].Points" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var i = 0;

    // Declare Syncfusion control settings
    var MaskedTextBox1 = new ejs.inputs.MaskedTextBox({
        "mask": "000-00-0000"
    });
    var DatePicker1 = new ejs.calendars.DatePicker({
        "placeholder": "Choose a Date"
    });

    var MaskedTextBox2 = new ejs.inputs.MaskedTextBox({
        "mask": "(999)-999-9999"
    });

    var MaskedTextBox3 = new ejs.inputs.MaskedTextBox({
        "mask": "(999)-999-9999"
    });

    var NumericTextBox1 = new ejs.inputs.NumericTextBox({
        "format": "n",
        "max": 50,
        "min": 0,
        "showSpinButton": false,
        "step": 1.0
    });

    $("#btnAdd").click(function () {

        i++;

        var xyz = $("#xyz").clone();

        xyz.find('label').each(function () {
            var attr = $(this).attr("for");
            if (attr != null) {
                $(this).attr("for", attr.replace('_0_', '_' + i + '_'));
            }
        });

        xyz.find('input').each(function () {
            this.name = this.name.replace('[0]', '[' + i + ']');
            this.id = this.id.replace('_0_', '_' + i + '_');
            $(this).val(null);
        });

        xyz.find('span').each(function () {
            var attr = $(this).data("valmsg-for");
            if (attr != null) {
                $(this).attr("data-valmsg-for", attr.replace('[0]', '[' + i + ']'));
            }
        });

        var divTitle = xyz.find('.applicant-title span')[0];
        divTitle.innerText = divTitle.innerText.replace('1', i + 1);

        $("#abc").append(xyz);

        // APPEND Syncfusion settings to copied controls
        MaskedTextBox1.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i + "__SocialSecurityNumber");
        DatePicker1.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i +"__Birthdate");
        MaskedTextBox2.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i + "__PhoneNumber");
        MaskedTextBox3.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i + "__WorkPhoneNumber");
        NumericTextBox1.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i + "__Points");
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have rendered the Syncfusion control as the wrapper component. while clicking the add button, you have cloned the already rendered wrapper components and once again re-rendered as a new set. So, cloned element is rendered again over on the wrapper component (so that you can get double border and icons in the components). Hence, it’s recommended to render the Syncfusion components as input elements instead of wrapper components to get rid of this issue. Here is the modified code snippet,

**[Clone.cshtml]**

```
<form method="post">
<div id="abc" class="row">
    <div id="xyz" class="col-md-3">
        <div class="card">
            <div class="card-header applicant-title">
                <span>Applicant 1</span>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].SocialSecurityNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @* Render the masked edit component as input *@
                        <input type="text" id="Applicants_0__SocialSecurityNumber" name="Applicants[0].SocialSecurityNumber" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].SocialSecurityNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].Birthdate" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @* Render the  datepicker component as input *@
                        <input type="text" id="Applicants_0__Birthdate" name="Applicants[0].Birthdate" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].Birthdate" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].PhoneNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @* Render the masked edit component as input *@
                        <input type="text" id="Applicants_0__PhoneNumber" name="Applicants[0].PhoneNumber" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].PhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].WorkPhoneNumber" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @* Render the masked edit component as input *@
                        <input type="text" id="Applicants_0__WorkPhoneNumber" name="Applicants[0].WorkPhoneNumber" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].WorkPhoneNumber" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group row">
                    <label asp-for="Applicants[0].Points" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label"></label>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @* Render the numeric text box component as input *@
                        <input type="text" id="Applicants_0__Points" name="Applicants[0].Points" />
                        <span asp-validation-for="Applicants[0].Points" class="text-danger"></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row mt-2">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="form-group row">
            <div class="col-sm-10">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

@section Scripts {

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    // Copy the clone element of the Syncfusion controls
    var xyz = $("#xyz").clone();
    // store the DOM string and assign the value to "xyz"
    xyz = xyz[0].outerHTML;
    // Take the another one copy of the outer HTML element into "copy" for further reference
    var copy = xyz;
    var i = 0;

    $("#btnAdd").click(function () {

        i++;
        // convert the outer HTML string into the HTML DOM object.
        xyz = $(xyz);
        // Assign the unique ID for the each card control
        xyz[0].setAttribute('id', 'xyz' + i);

        xyz.find('label').each(function () {
            var attr = $(this).attr("for");
            if (attr != null) {
                $(this).attr("for", attr.replace('_0_', '_' + i + '_'));
            }
        });

        xyz.find('input').each(function () {
            this.name = this.name.replace('[0]', '[' + i + ']');
            this.id = this.id.replace('_0_', '_' + i + '_');
            $(this).val(null);
        });

        xyz.find('span').each(function () {
            var attr = $(this).data("valmsg-for");
            if (attr != null) {
                $(this).attr("data-valmsg-for", attr.replace('[0]', '[' + i + ']'));
            }
        });

        var divTitle = xyz.find('.applicant-title span')[0];
        divTitle.innerText = divTitle.innerText.replace('1', i + 1);

        $("#abc").append(xyz);

        // Declare new instance for Syncfusion control settings will helps to render the component as a new set without any issues.

        // Render masked text box component
        var MaskedTextBox1 = new ejs.inputs.MaskedTextBox({
            "mask": "000-00-0000"
        });

        // Render the datepicker component
        var DatePicker1 = new ejs.calendars.DatePicker({
            "placeholder": "Choose a Date"
        });

        // Render the masked text box component
        var MaskedTextBox2 = new ejs.inputs.MaskedTextBox({
            "mask": "(999)-999-9999"
        });

        // Render the masked text box component
        var MaskedTextBox3 = new ejs.inputs.MaskedTextBox({
            "mask": "(999)-999-9999"
        });

        // Render the numeric text box component
        var NumericTextBox1 = new ejs.inputs.NumericTextBox({
            "format": "n",
            "max": 50,
            "min": 0,
            "showSpinButton": false,
            "step": 1.0
        });

        // APPEND Syncfusion settings to copied controls
        MaskedTextBox1.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i + "__SocialSecurityNumber");
        DatePicker1.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i + "__Birthdate");
        MaskedTextBox2.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i + "__PhoneNumber");
        MaskedTextBox3.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i + "__WorkPhoneNumber");
        NumericTextBox1.appendTo("#Applicants_" + i + "__Points");  
        // Assign the reference copy of outer element to the "xyz" again
        xyz = copy;
    });

    // Render the initially defined masked text box component
    var mask = new ejs.inputs.MaskedTextBox({
        "mask": "000-00-0000"
    });
    mask.appendTo("#Applicants_0__SocialSecurityNumber");

    // Render the initially defined datepicker component
    var datepicker = new ejs.calendars.DatePicker({
        "placeholder": "Choose a Date"
    });
    datepicker.appendTo("#Applicants_0__Birthdate");

    // Render the initially defined masked text box component
    var mask2 = new ejs.inputs.MaskedTextBox({
        "mask": "(999)-999-9999"
    });
    mask2.appendTo("#Applicants_0__PhoneNumber");

    // Render the initially defined masked text box component
    var mask3 = new ejs.inputs.MaskedTextBox({
        "mask": "(999)-999-9999"
    });
    mask3.appendTo("#Applicants_0__WorkPhoneNumber");

    // Render the initially defined numeric text box component
    var numeric = new ejs.inputs.NumericTextBox({
        "format": "n",
        "max": 50,
        "min": 0,
        "showSpinButton": false,
        "step": 1.0,
        "showClearButton": false
    });
    numeric.appendTo("#Applicants_0__Points");

</script>
```

}

You can refer to the sample from [here](http://www.syncfusion.com/downloads/support/directtrac/general/ze/SyncfusionSamples-527651057).